# Data frame/matrix row times vector/list element wise

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, weighted-average

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
raw<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
mat<- matrix(raw,ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
```

to get me

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Plus a vector or list

```
vector<-c(1,2,3)
```

What I need to do is to multiply each row by the corresponding vector entry
i.e 1*1 , 4*2, 7* 3 etc.

My final goal is to calculate a weighted average of row and vector.

I tried using

```
apply(c(mat,vector),1,prod)
```

I would like to know if it can be done in an elegant way at once or how I can calculate the row*vector product correctly.

thanks

Comment: thanks, now i can use apply(new_mat,1,mean)

Comment: `mat*rep(vector, each=3)`

Comment: @jogo's solution is actually much faster, so that one should be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the operation in your question you can do

```
mat * rep(vector, each=3)  # or
mat * rep(vector, each=nrow(mat))  # or
mat * matrix(vector, nrow(mat), ncol(mat), byrow=TRUE)
```

In the comments I read you want to calculate the rowwise mean for the resulting matrix. So you can do:

```
rowMeans(mat*rep(vector, each=nrow(mat))) # or:
apply(mat, 1, weighted.mean, w=vector)*mean(vector) # both steps together
```

Normally the function `rowMeans()` is faster than alternative calculations.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sweep` to apply the product function over the columns of `mat`:

```
sweep(mat, 2, vector, '*')
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    8   21
#[2,]    2   10   24
#[3,]    3   12   27
```